# How do I configure the timeout on HttpEndRequest?

Tags: c++, winapi, timeout

Background: I'm maintaining an old C++ app that communicates with my company's servers. No one at the company (including me) has any significant experience with C++ or with many of the other technologies being used.

The problem: I am trying to upload a file with code that looks like this:

```
if(HttpSendRequestEx(hReq, &InBuf, NULL, HSR_INITIATE, 0))
{
    unsigned long ulWrote;
    BOOL bWrote;
    bWrote = InternetWriteFile(hReq, postData, postDataLength, &ulWrote);

    if(bWrote)
    {
        if(!HttpEndRequest(hReq, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            DWORD errorCode = GetLastError(); // 12002 - timeout
        }
    }
}
```

There's lots of other error-handling going on here, but I've stripped it down to where I'm seeing a problem.

Small files will upload without a problem, larger files (~25MB) are encountering a timeout. Even though the timeout is occurring, many times the file will upload successfully, so I don't think it's a problem on the server side. Just suppressing or ignoring the error seems wrong but I haven't found any way to set the timeout to a more reasonable level.

Answer (score 3):

WININET provides [`InternetSetOption()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#scope) its behaviour, in your case look at the the [`INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT) flag.

Comment: I tried with INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT and INTERNET_OPTION_DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT all set to 2 minutes. I still get a timeout at 30 seconds. InternetQueryOption verified that the values are being set correctly.